# How to determine a list of servers that share current folder

Tags: rhel, shared-folders

On `linux` `Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.7 (Maipo)` I have several folders that are shared between different servers (and users), how can I get the info about who else (which server/user) is also using the current folder? I want to see a table with smth like:

```
server1 - space1
server2 - space2
total space - space1 + space2
```

For instance, if I run `df -H` I see that the current folder where I am in (which is also my `$HOME` directory) has `4T` of allocated memory, and `3.5T` is used but I am using only `50Gb`, so obviously it is shared with someone else. I am not that familiar with these `linux` sharing concepts, so if you could recommend some sources, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: We need more info. you say shared between servers and users??? What are you sharing the folder with NFS, samba, etc. 
without knowing more, play around with lsof.

Comment: Ok, I looked and it is `NFS`. One folder is shared between users somehow. So, for instance they allocated `3T` for a group of `3` people and each user has its space in `/fsdhome/{username}`. Now I am not sure that I understand this architecture and how all of that is done. Then, a user was created and its home folder: `opt/seqr`. There each user can log in and use: it is shared among them. However, the amount of memory allocated there again is bigger than what each user sees is occupied when he or she logs in. If I am not mistaken, for this second space there are several server nodes.

Comment: I described two different cases: first is the space that is shared between the users when they log in; second is common space for all of the users (that represents itself just one user to which users can log in) that is shared between several server nodes. So, my goal is to figure out a command or a set of commands that can tell me more info about it.